# Rails query selecting last record with distinct column

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I need to make a query where I retrieve the "last" records of a distinct column.

I have a model, Languages, which has 3 columns:

```
Locale -> es | en | de
Version ->  1 | 2 | 3
Data -> aaa | bbb | ccc
```

There can be duplicated records by locale, by not by version. For example:

```
es | 1 | aaa
es | 2 | aab
es | 3 | aba
en | 1 | bbb
en | 2 | bab
```

And in that example, I need to retrieve this result:

```
es | 3 | aba
en | 2 | bab
```

There will be the last 2 versions of a language. I'm doing this query right now:

```
Language.all.order('created_at desc').group(:locale)
```

but I'm getting:

```
es | 2 | aba
en | 1 | bab
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The versions have been created in order so the created_at desc is correct :)

Comment: will this help  `Language.all.group_by(&:locale).map{|s| s.last.last}`

Comment: Thanks a lot Athar! This actually does the job :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a raw MySQL query which will give you the result set you want:

```
SELECT lang1.*
FROM Languages lang1 INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT l.Locale, MAX(l.Version) AS MaxVersion
    FROM Languages l
    GROUP BY l.Locale
) lang2
ON lang1.Locale = lang2.Locale AND lang1.Version = lang2.MaxVersion
```

I am not a Ruby person, so this is as much help as I can offer.  I'm hoping that you know how to translate a MySQL query into the query language you have in the OP.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That works! I don't know if there are a better solution in rails, but I am going to update my question with the result! Thanks again!

Comment: But this doesn't provide an answer to the OP question:  **Rails query** selecting last record with distinct column

Comment: I updated the results, because the two of them are valid. Maybe the SQL one will help someone! Thanks to all!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks all for your answers! This are the results!

### Second option

Even if the first option was correct, after another comment, this is the final version and is the one I'm using (which I think is more correct for my environment):

```
Language.all.group_by(&:locale).map{|s| s.last.last}
```

### First option

If this helps to someone, this is what worked for me after Tim's answer:

```
query = "SELECT lang1.* " +
        "FROM languages lang1 INNER JOIN " +
        "(" +
            "SELECT l.locale, MAX(l.version) AS max_version " +
            "FROM languages l " +
            "GROUP BY l.locale" +
        ") lang2 " +
        "ON lang1.locale = lang2.locale AND lang1.version = lang2.max_version"
languages = Language.find_by_sql(query)
```

Maybe there's a cleaner solution in ruby, but this retrieve the correct results!